Syntax error macroexpanding defact, upgrading clojure 1.9 to 1.12
I'm getting the following error when upgrading from clojure 1.9 to clojure 1.12
Syntax error macroexpanding defact at (up/lib/pvm/fact.clj:23:18).
Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol

The offending code is this:
(defmacro defact

  ([name fields] (defact &form &env name nil fields nil nil))

  ([name doc-string? fields] (defact &form &env name doc-string? fields nil nil))

  ([name fields meta-key meta-val] (defact &form &env name nil fields meta-key meta-val))

  ([name doc-string? fields meta-key meta-val & meta-data]
   (let [gname name
         kfields (into [] (map keyword fields))
         classword (str *ns* "/" gname)
         md-list (when (and meta-key meta-val)
                   [meta-key meta-val])
         md-list (if meta-data
                   (concat md-list meta-data)
                   md-list)
         md (apply hash-map md-list)
         md (if (empty? md) nil md)
         doc (or doc-string? (str "Positional factory function for map " classword "."))]
     `(do
        (def ~(symbol (str gname '-meta)) ~md)
        (def ~(symbol gname) ~classword)
        (defn ~(symbol (str gname '?))
          [m#]
          (= ~classword (:fact-type m#)))

        (defn ~(symbol (str 'map-> gname))
          ~doc
          ([m#]
           (with-meta
             (assoc m# :fact-type ~classword)
             ~md)))

        (defn ~(symbol (str '-> gname))
          ~doc
          ([& m#]
           (if (= ~(count kfields) (count m#))
             (with-meta
               (assoc
                 (zipmap ~kfields m#)
                 :fact-type ~classword)
               ~md)
             (throw (ex-info "Incorrect number of arguments" {:got (count m#) :desired ~(count kfields)}))))))))

   )


This is very old legacy code that we need to upgrade the clojure version. For some reason I can still build the uberjar but it fails during lein check, which is part of our build process.
I think the issue has to do with the change in 1.9.0-alpha3, but I can't find anything on the recommended solution. This is also low level code that we can't get rid of. Any help would be greatly appreciated
I have tried removing and moving around various arguments and such however I'm not very familiar with clojure and this seems to be leveraging some features of the language I don't fully understand and I can't seem to find resources on.
Complete report:
{:clojure.main/message
 "Syntax error macroexpanding defact at (up/lib/pvm/fact.clj:23:18).\nDon't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol\n",
 :clojure.main/triage
 {:clojure.error/phase :macro-syntax-check,
  :clojure.error/line 23,
  :clojure.error/column 18,
  :clojure.error/source "fact.clj",
  :clojure.error/symbol defact,
  :clojure.error/path "up/lib/pvm/fact.clj",
  :clojure.error/class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,
  :clojure.error/cause
  "Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol"},
 :clojure.main/trace
 {:via
  [{:type clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException,
    :message
    "Syntax error macroexpanding defact at (up/lib/pvm/fact.clj:23:18).",
    :data
    {:clojure.error/phase :macro-syntax-check,
     :clojure.error/line 23,
     :clojure.error/column 18,
     :clojure.error/source "up/lib/pvm/fact.clj",
     :clojure.error/symbol defact},
    :at [clojure.lang.Compiler macroexpand1 "Compiler.java" 7533]}
   {:type java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,
    :message "Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol",
    :at [clojure.lang.RT seqFrom "RT.java" 577]}],
  :trace
  [[clojure.lang.RT seqFrom "RT.java" 577]
   [clojure.lang.RT seq "RT.java" 557]
   [clojure.core$seq__5484 invokeStatic "core.clj" 139]
   [clojure.core$map$fn__5952 invoke "core.clj" 2763]
   [clojure.lang.LazySeq force "LazySeq.java" 50]
   [clojure.lang.LazySeq realize "LazySeq.java" 89]
   [clojure.lang.LazySeq seq "LazySeq.java" 106]
   [clojure.lang.RT seq "RT.java" 555]
   [clojure.core$seq__5484 invokeStatic "core.clj" 139]
   [clojure.core.protocols$seq_reduce invokeStatic "protocols.clj" 24]
   [clojure.core.protocols$fn__8258 invokeStatic "protocols.clj" 74]
   [clojure.core.protocols$fn__8258 invoke "protocols.clj" 74]
   [clojure.core.protocols$fn__8199$G__8194__8212
    invoke
    "protocols.clj"
    13]
   [clojure.core$reduce invokeStatic "core.clj" 6965]
   [clojure.core$into invokeStatic "core.clj" 7038]
   [clojure.core$into invoke "core.clj" 7029]
   [up.lib.pvm.fact$defact invokeStatic "fact.clj" 31]
   [up.lib.pvm.fact$defact doInvoke "fact.clj" 6]
   [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 175]
   [clojure.lang.Var applyTo "Var.java" 707]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler macroexpand1 "Compiler.java" 7516]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyzeSeq "Compiler.java" 7607]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyze "Compiler.java" 7312]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyze "Compiler.java" 7268]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser parse "Compiler.java" 6640]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod parse "Compiler.java" 5982]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr parse "Compiler.java" 4544]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyzeSeq "Compiler.java" 7619]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyze "Compiler.java" 7312]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyzeSeq "Compiler.java" 7609]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyze "Compiler.java" 7312]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler access$200 "Compiler.java" 43]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr$Parser parse "Compiler.java" 589]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyzeSeq "Compiler.java" 7621]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyze "Compiler.java" 7312]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler analyze "Compiler.java" 7268]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7695]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7680]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler load "Compiler.java" 8157]
   [clojure.lang.RT loadResourceScript "RT.java" 401]
   [clojure.lang.RT loadResourceScript "RT.java" 392]
   [clojure.lang.RT load "RT.java" 479]
   [clojure.lang.RT load "RT.java" 444]
   [clojure.core$load$fn__6929 invoke "core.clj" 6189]
   [clojure.core$load invokeStatic "core.clj" 6188]
   [clojure.core$load doInvoke "core.clj" 6172]
   [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke "RestFn.java" 411]
   [user$eval52338$fn__52349
    invoke
    "form-init13786016343757455939.clj"
    1]
   [user$eval52338 invokeStatic "form-init13786016343757455939.clj" 1]
   [user$eval52338 invoke "form-init13786016343757455939.clj" 1]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7691]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7681]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler load "Compiler.java" 8157]
   [clojure.lang.Compiler loadFile "Compiler.java" 8095]
   [clojure.main$load_script invokeStatic "main.clj" 476]
   [clojure.main$init_opt invokeStatic "main.clj" 478]
   [clojure.main$init_opt invoke "main.clj" 478]
   [clojure.main$initialize invokeStatic "main.clj" 509]
   [clojure.main$null_opt invokeStatic "main.clj" 543]
   [clojure.main$null_opt invoke "main.clj" 540]
   [clojure.main$main invokeStatic "main.clj" 665]
   [clojure.main$main doInvoke "main.clj" 617]
   [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 140]
   [clojure.lang.Var applyTo "Var.java" 707]
   [clojure.main main "main.java" 40]],
  :cause "Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol",
  :phase :macro-syntax-check}}

I modified the first call to:
  ([name fields]
    (println (str "defact: " name "---" fields))
    (defact &form &env name nil fields nil nil))

and when I run the server the following is printed:
defact: BasicSetReq []
defact: BasicSetResp [docs-map]


Tracing execution is your friend. Find out which arguments are passed during the macro's invocation, and subsequently which line is getting which symbol where it expects a sequence, and you're much closer to understanding.

How do I do that? My understanding is that macro expansion is done at compile time and this error is only triggered during lein check and not during any other phase

There should still be a stack trace, at the very least, that would point you to the exact line inside the macro where it breaks. And you can check any passed values without having to rely on any additional tools or config - just add some println statements to the macro.

I agree with Charles and Eugene - you don't debug a huge macro with just the summary of the error message. But also, I don't see how this ever compiled. A macro calling itself should usually use syntax-quote, not a bare call to itself like a function would. The macro definition should fail to compile because, for example, the [name fields] arity makes an illegal call to defact with a symbol for fields instead of a sequence. Notably, this matches the error message you quote!

I updated the post with the full report. The server seems to run fine even with the code as is. Maybe its because this syntax is still supported somehow? Again I only get this error when I run lein check. I think its something to do with the &form and &env arguments which were deprecated in 1.9.0-alpha3, but I'm not sure what they should be. Also up/lib/pvm/fact.clj:23:18 corresponds to ([name fields] (defact &form &env name nil fields nil nil))

Instead of (defact &form &env name nil fields nil nil) do \(defact ~name nil ~fields nil nil)`, and similar for the other arity.

Syntax error was due to &form and &env and how the macro was overloaded. The overloaded function calls of:
  ([name fields] (defact &form &env name nil fields nil nil))

  ([name doc-string? fields] (defact &form &env name doc-string? fields nil nil))

  ([name fields meta-key meta-val] (defact &form &env name nil fields meta-key meta-val))

Needed to change to:
  ([name fields] `(defact ~name nil ~fields nil nil))

  ([name doc-string? fields] `(defact ~name ~doc-string? ~fields nil nil))

  ([name fields meta-key meta-val] `(defact ~name nil ~fields ~meta-key ~meta-val))

